# Had the Catholic Church a tradition of commemorating Abraham's sacrifice?

Tags: catholicism, tradition, abraham, feasts

[Eid ul-Adha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eid_al-Adha) or Bakrid is celebtrated all over the world by Muslims to commemorate the sacrifice that Abraham  offered in obedience to God.

My question is: Had the Catholic Church any tradition of commemorating, in a significant way,  the scrifice of Abraham as the forerunner of the scrifice that God the Father would later offer at Mount Calvary through His Only Son Jesus?

Answer (score 1):

The only Catholic Church tradition of commemorating the sacrifice of Abraham (Gen. 22:1-18) is at the [Easter vigil](http://www.usccb.org/bible/readings/041517.cfm) with the second reading being the actual account of Abraham taking his son Isaac to the land of Moriah to be sacrificed to God.

It is not the tradition of the Church to commemorate Old Testament events in themselves, but rather to associate them in the liturgy in light of the Church's faith in her Savior Jesus Christ.

It could also be noted that the Patriarch Abraham is commemorated on October 9 in the [Vicariate of St. James](https://catholicchurch-holyland.com/?p=221) (Hebrew Catholics) in the Holy Land.

> Saint Abraham is remembered on a feast day of his own – in the Orthodox Church on October 11 and in the Catholic Church the feast has been transferred to October 9. The fact that the date is shared in the Eastern and the Western Church proof of the antiquity of this feast that dates back before the schism between East and West in the eleventh century. However, this is not surprising when one considers the importance of Abraham our father – who is our father in body and spirit. - [Feast of Saint Abraham – October 9](http://www.catholic.co.il/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2496:feast-of-saint-abraham-october-9&catid=35&Itemid=141&lang=en)

[image: Abraham offering his son Isaac to be Sacrificed]

Abraham offering his son Isaac to be Sacrificed

Of further interest here is a related question I asked on [**Mi Yodeya SE**](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour): [Are there any Jewish or Hebrew traditions that hold that the Passover and the binding of Isaac were on the same day (15 Nisan)?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94810/are-there-any-jewish-or-hebrew-traditions-that-hold-that-the-passover-and-the-bi)